# Old movie, maybe 80s or early 90s with drakes being ridden through a canyon

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I remember seeing this move where these people were riding drakes through a canyon of some sort. I think the drakes were fighting one another in the air. It was live-action, definitely not animated. It was in English. I was probably 8 when I first saw it so the only scene I remember was the scene with the drakes flying through the valley or canyon of sorts. That's all I remember.

Does anybody know what it was called?

Comment: What language was it in? Was it live-action or animated? Do you have any memories of the characters (descriptions, names, etc)? Do you have any memories of the actual plot?

Comment: It was live-action, definitely not animated. It was in English. I was probably 8 when I first saw it so the only scene I remember was the scene with the drakes flying through the valley or canyon of sorts. That's all I remember.

Comment: I assume by "drakes" you're referring to smallish dragons? Were they armored at all? Were they normal-looking (ie - traditional European) dragons, Oriental dragons, furry white dragons with dog faces, etc.?

Comment: They look like traditional European dragons. Definitely not oriental.

Comment: When were you 8? We have no idea what year this would be...

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to go on in the original question, so this answer may be premature. However, there aren't many live-action films that depict people riding dragons while fighting. You may be thinking of the live-action Dungeons & Dragons movie which released in 2000. It had several distance shots of dragons flying through canyons, and then the large battle at the end had the queen riding a dragon amongst large buildings while battling other dragons.

Watch the trailer below and see if it looks familiar. There are several shots of the dragons spread throughout the trailer.

If you have problems viewing the embedded video, [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SnA2rv4ros) to view it on YouTube.